# How do I make tramp+eshell use my environment customized in the remote ~/.bash_profile

Tags: eshell, tramp, path, environment

I have set up custom $PATH in my ~/.bash_profile on a remote machine (for programs installed user-locally by `nix` and `cabal`).

I use eshell and tramp to issue commands on the remote machine (`cd /remotehost:somedir`; then commands). (I chose this method instead of the common SSH-sessions in a terminal primarily because I'm using a bad connection and SSH-sessions get interrupted very often, so I can't count on being able to login, cd, and issue a command before the connection is interrupted.)

Unfortunately, my custom PATH is not honored in this situation, and some of the programs are not found.

What would be the nicest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Other related discussions: [Tramp using ssh does not source .bash_profile / .profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10463152/94687), 
[emacs tramp how to avoid bash_profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10712654/94687), [how to get bash_profile out of the way?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/tramp-devel/2012-06/msg00003.html), ['exec /bin/bash --login' in ~/.profile](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.tramp/7632), ...

Answer (score 8):

This question [has been already answered by rekado (thanks!)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2106/5165) (as a reply to another more general question about eshell):

> You can configure TRAMP to respect the PATH variable on the remote
>   machine (for remote eshell sessions) by adding
>   `'tramp-own-remote-path` to the list `'tramp-remote-path`:
>
> ```
> (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
> ```
>
> By default, eshell will not adopt the remote PATH settings.

As for other environment variables, there is no special approach as for `PATH`: one can set them through `tramp-remote-process-environment` (as documented in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-processes.html):

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment
              (format "DISPLAY=%s" (getenv "DISPLAY")))
```

and I don't know of a way that would read the ones set in the remote `~/.bash_profile`. So you need to repeat them in this variable on the local side in Emacs as a workaround, which is not totally convenient because different remote hosts might need different values.

As for `EDITOR` specifically, of course, doing it [with `with-editor`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/893/5165) would be more convenient and appropriate.

Comment: I don't see that this works. Perhaps, that's because I set and export a custom PATH in `~/.bash_profile` (contrary to `~/.profile`) which I have seen in some docs concerning these `tramp-*` vars...

Comment: This was fixed in Tramp last December. Try the development version of Tramp.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out in this answer that adding `'tramp-own-remote-path` to `tramp-remote-path` causes tramp to open a login shell (using the `-l` argument), thereby sourcing `~/.profile` – this means that per-host customization can be done in `~/.profile` for things other than `PATH`.